# Есть ли в swift функция вычисления Логарифма log_a(b)

Tags: xcode, swift

Пытался найти встроенную функцию вычисления логарифма от числа A по B. 
Встроенные функции такие как `log(Double) //Натуральный логарифм`, `log2(Double) // логарифм по основанию 2` и `log10(Double)// по основанию 10` соответственно.

Не как не смог найти Функцию подобной `log_a(b)`. Имеется ли такая?

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает формула мены основания у логарифма? log(a,x) = log(b,x)/log(b,a)

Comment: А зачем??? `log_a(b) = log_c(b) / log_c(a)`

Comment: @pavel Да меня она устраивает. Но зачем лишнее действие.

Comment: @andy.37 Да думал что есть встроенная функция.

Comment: @andy.37 Спасибо за ответ)))